# Plotly Scattergeo does not expand size

Tags: plotly, geospatial, plotly-dash, scatter-plot

I've got a plotly Scattergeo figure that only uses about 1/3rd of the screen in a Dash application. I've tried setting the height and width of the plot explicitly, but without any luck. There does not appear to be any css that causes this issue either.

The gray Scattergeo is bigger but is clipped in the clipgroup that seems to be autogenerated. I don't see how I can change its values.

How can I let this autoexpand to use the whole paper size. The image underneath shows the papersize as blue)

[image: plotly Scattergeo with blue paper_bgcolor]

The code producing this image:

```
# Create a scattergeo trace with square markers
trace = go.Scattergeo(
    lat=plot['lat'],
    lon=plot['lon'],
    mode='markers+text',
    marker=dict(
        size=10,
        color='blue',
        opacity=0.7,
        symbol='square'
    ),
    text=plot['Callsign'],
    textposition='middle right',
    textfont=dict(size=8, color='white'),
    hovertemplate="<b>%{text}</b><br>" +
        "Tracknumber: %{customdata[0]}<br>" +
        "Altitude: %{customdata[1]}<br>" +
        "TAS: %{customdata[2]}<br>" +
        "Date: %{customdata[3]}",
    customdata=customdata
)
# Define the layout
layout = go.Layout(
    geo=dict(
        projection=dict(type='mercator', scale=33),
        resolution=50,
        center=dict(lat=frame["lat"], lon=frame["lon"]),
        scope='europe',
        bgcolor='black',
        showcountries=True,
        countrycolor='black',
        landcolor='gray',
        lakecolor='black',
    ),
    coloraxis_showscale=False,
    showlegend=False,
    xaxis={"title": "", "showgrid": False, "zeroline": False, "visible": False },
    yaxis={"title": "", "showgrid": False, "zeroline": False, "visible": False },
)
# Create the figure
fig = go.Figure(data=trace, layout=layout)


fig.update_layout(
    paper_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,255,1)",
    plot_bgcolor="rgba(255,0,0,0)",
    margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0, "autoexpand":True},
    height=500
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the projection clipping is dictated by the scope.

Although we can set the [lataxis/lonaxis ranges](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/geo/#layout-geo-lataxis-range) to define the boundaries of the clip region, these are overridden if the scope is different than 'world' (default), or to be more precise : restricting the scope involves a "composite" region (clip region within a clip region) as the clipping area. For example, setting `scope='europe'` produces a narrow clipPath, `scope='north america'` produces a less constricting fit, etc., and this is regardless of the outer clip region determined by the ranges.

Yet the documentation says :

`lataxis/lonaxis`

> `range` - Sets the range of this axis (in degrees), **sets the map's
> clipped coordinates**.

... without mentioning the impact of having a restricted scope.

Anyway, in order to obtain the expected layout/ratio, use `scope='world'` (or leave it unset), adjust `center`, `lataxis_range`,  and `lonaxis_range` as necessary, and only then adjust the projection `scale`.

Here an example that produces a "square ratio" :

```py
layout = go.Layout(
    geo=dict(
        projection=dict(type='mercator', scale=1), # start with scale 1, then adjust
        resolution=50,
        center=dict(lat=frame["lat"], lon=frame["lon"]),
        scope='world',            # prevent clipping the clipping area
        bgcolor='black',
        showcountries=True,
        countrycolor='black',
        landcolor='gray',
        lakecolor='black',
        lataxis_range=[0, 90],    # defines clip height
        lonaxis_range=[-75, 105], # defines clip width
    ),
    coloraxis_showscale=False,
    showlegend=False,
    xaxis={"title": "", "showgrid": False, "zeroline": False, "visible": False },
    yaxis={"title": "", "showgrid": False, "zeroline": False, "visible": False },
)
```

Or, if you need the map "unclipped", ie. looking like as a standard "large/full" rectangular world map :

```py
#...
        lataxis_range=[-90, 90],
        lonaxis_range=[-180, 180],
```